# Is it possible to define a pointer to a varying type that automatically dereferences as a specific type?

Tags: c++, casting, type-conversion

Is it possible to define a pointer to an unknown numeric type, say `int` or `double`, that always returns a specific type, say `double`, on dereferencing?

I started doing this,

```
int    a = 7;
double b = 3.14;

void* c = static_cast<void*>(&a);
void* d = static_cast<void*>(&b);

double e = *(static_cast<double*>(c));
double f = *(static_cast<double*>(d));
```

but of course, casting an `int*` to a `double*` is just going to produce gibberish for `e` since we'd be reinterpreting the internal bits for an `int` as if they were in `double` format.

I tried in earnest to answer in advance *why* I'd need to do this, since certainly there must be a better design option, but the explanation got wordy. In short, it has to do with legacy code, some parts of which I can't modify, and since we're planning on rewriting the affected components anyway, I'm currently investigating whether a workaround is possible.

In case my watered-down version is *too* watered down, here's one more level of detail. I'm working with a method that *must* return a `double`, by dereferencing what used to be a `void` pointer to a `double` (in shared memory), but now may point to an `int` too. There is a "hook" that's invoked when the pointer is set to point to another location, at which point it's known whether it's going to point to a `double` or an `int`. So the only thing I can think of doing, is storing the type (or setting a flag) in a member variable during that hook, and casting to a pointer of that type before dereferencing.

But I was hoping someone would know a handy trick or technique I may have missed. Some other way of storing pointers or organizing types so that I won't have to modify the hook at all (I'd really like to avoid doing that, for other, cumbersome-to-explain reasons).

Comment: If it points to int, you can convert int to double and return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ is strongly typed. An expression `(expr)` always has the same static type. It may have a variable dynamic type, *if* the static type is a base type of the dynamic type. That's obviously not the case here.

So, the only solution is to write both casts:

```
if (flag)
  std::cout << * static_cast<int*>(ptr);
else
  std::cout << * static_cast<double*>(ptr);
```

Both expressions have a statically-determined type, and at runtime you choose the expression (and thus the type) which is correct for the data in `ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

C and C++ doesn't "store" what type something is - it is known by the compiler, but once the code has been compiled, this information is discarded. It comes out of the expression that you write - and of course a `void` is just a special type to indicate "this has no type".

You will need to track, yourself, somehow if the content is `int` or `double`. If you can't do that, then it's "busted", can't be done.